# ngx-file-drop module Clickable option?

Tags: angular

I'm beginning with angular 6 and i'm trying to create a basic folder content Upload.

I'm using 'ngx-file-drop' for upload my folder with a drag and drop but the click on it don t work for open the file Browser.

Someone had already try to set a status (click) on this module and open the file Browser or it's impossible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code, the `[showBrowseBtn]="true"` will allow to open the folder on click of label Upload File

```html
<file-drop [showBrowseBtn]="true" browseBtnLabel="Upload File" multiple="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<a>` to it and put `"target="_blank"` in the tag.

If this is what you mean